# How to provide an MWE if my question is about the behavior of a specific font I've uploaded to the project?

Tags: support

I'm working on a LuaLaTex project for which there are, as far as I know, only three appropriate fonts in existence, all of which I have to upload to use and all of which produce the issue I'm trying to deal with. But if I put together an MWE using a standard font, the issue doesn't crop up.

Is there a way to post a useful MWE on `tex.stackexchange` referring to a specific, non-standard font?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the fonts are proprietary, then there’s not too much you can do except for mention that those fonts are the ones that caused the problem and hope that somebody has a version of them. If the fonts are available freely, but not part of the standard distribution you can just provide a link to the font. It would be important, in either case, however, to give a minimal example that would reproduce the problem with the font that you’re using.

Comment: Thank you! I'm pretty sure that at least one of them is available freely, so I'll write up a question with your answer in mind. I really appreciate the help!